# Multiple string variable array swift

Tags: swift

I have two arrays, I want to collect these arrays one arrayde. So what I want to do is to have

> gradepickervalues 1 + gradepickervalues 2 + gradepickervalues 3 =
>   gradePickerValues

What do I have to do about it? It's not working in the code right now.

```
 var picker = UIPickerView()

    var gradePickerValues1 = [String]()
    var gradePickerValues2 = [String]()
    var gradePickerValues3 = [String]()
    var gradePickerValues = [String]()

    @objc func GetDevice() {


        if !chipnumber.text!.isEmpty {
            let ref = Database.database().reference().child(chipnumber.text!).child("titles").child("0").child("DeviceName")

            ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                //let value: NSDictionary = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
                let dic = snapshot.value as! String
                self.gradePickerValues = [dic]
            })

        }

        if !chipnumber2.text!.isEmpty {
            let ref = Database.database().reference().child(chipnumber2.text!).child("titles").child("0").child("DeviceName")

            ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                //let value: NSDictionary = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
                let dic = snapshot.value as! String
                self.gradePickerValues = [dic]

            })

        }

        if !chipnumber3.text!.isEmpty {
            let ref = Database.database().reference().child(chipnumber3.text!).child("titles").child("0").child("DeviceName")

            ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                //let value: NSDictionary = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
                let dic = snapshot.value as! String
                self.gradePickerValues = [dic]

            })

        }

    }
```

Comment: Why not `self.gradePickerValues.append(dic)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you overwite `gradePickerValues` in every response , You can try to use

```
var picker = UIPickerView() 
var gradePickerValues1 = [String]()
var gradePickerValues2 = [String]()
var gradePickerValues3 = [String]()
var gradePickerValues = [String]()

let g = DispatchGroup()

@objc func GetDevice() {



    if !chipnumber.text!.isEmpty {

        g.enter()

        let ref = Database.database().reference().child(chipnumber.text!).child("titles").child("0").child("DeviceName")

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            //let value: NSDictionary = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
            let dic = snapshot.value as! String
            self.gradePickerValues1 = [dic]
            self.g.leave()
        })

    }

    if !chipnumber2.text!.isEmpty {

        g.enter()

        let ref = Database.database().reference().child(chipnumber2.text!).child("titles").child("0").child("DeviceName")

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            //let value: NSDictionary = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
            let dic = snapshot.value as! String
            self.gradePickerValues2 = [dic]
            self.g.leave()
        })

    }

    if !chipnumber3.text!.isEmpty {

        g.enter()

        let ref = Database.database().reference().child(chipnumber3.text!).child("titles").child("0").child("DeviceName")

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            //let value: NSDictionary = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
            let dic = snapshot.value as! String
            self.gradePickerValues3 = [dic]
            self.g.leave()

        })

    }

    g.notify(queue:.main) {

        self.gradePickerValues = gradePickerValues1 + gradePickerValues2 + gradePickerValues3

        print(self.gradePickerValues)
    }

}
```